# Custom scipy.spatial.distance.pdist

Tags: python, numpy, distance

This is my first attempt using scipy, can you please help me by implementing this function?

[image: this]

This is what I managed to write...

```
d = pdist(X, lambda u, v: np.sqrt(((u-v)/(np.max(u,v)).sum()))
```

Comment: For reference: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist

Comment: whats your problem with what you have done?

Comment: How can I divide by k (the number of elements)?